# "Invalid conversion" error when visiting a variant of functions

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

I am trying to `std::visit` a `std::variant` of `std::function` types.

Why does the following code not compile:

```
#include <functional>
#include <variant>

int main()
{
  std::variant<
      std::function< int () >,
      std::function< float () >
  > func_variant {std::in_place_index<0>, [] () { return 42; }};

  auto object = std::visit( [] (auto& func) { return func(); }, func_variant);

  return 0;
}
```

The error happens in the call of `std::visit`, where it says:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘std::__success_type<float>::type (*)(main()::<lambda(auto:1&)>&&, std::variant<std::function<int()>, std::function<float()> >&)’ {aka ‘float (*)(main()::<lambda(auto:1&)>&&, std::variant<std::function<int()>, std::function<float()> >&)’} to ‘int (*)(main()::<lambda(auto:1&)>&&, std::variant<std::function<int()>, std::function<float()> >&)’ [-fpermissive]
       { return _Array_type{&__visit_invoke}; }
                                           ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your `std::function` types returns a different type, so the return type of the lambda you are passing to `std::visit` depends on the type of the selected element of the lambda. This means that the auto-type-deduction can't work, as the call to `std::visit` must have a single return type which is independent of which element of the variant is active.

You could make a return type variant: `using returns=std::variant<int,float>` and then cast the return in your lambda to that:

```
using returns=std::variant<int,float>;
auto object = std::visit( [] (auto& func) { return returns(func()); }, func_variant);
```

That way the return type of your lambda is the same in all cases, but you will then need to query the result to see what you got.